# Jquery Paging creation without plugin

Tags: jquery, html, pagination

Hi I am leveraging the jquery to create pagination for a demo html table.The idea is not to use any plugin but for sharpening my skills in jquery writing logic to get the job done.

Say following is the html structure:

```
 <div>
    <input type='hidden' id='current_page' />
    <input type='hidden' id='show_per_page' />
    <div id='page_navigation'>
    </div>
    <table id="paginate" id="table1" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                One
            </td>
            <td>
                Two
            </td>
            <td>
                Three
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                4
            </td>
            <td>
                5
            </td>
            <td>
                6
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                7
            </td>
            <td>
                8
            </td>
            <td>
                9
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                40
            </td>
            <td>
                50
            </td>
            <td>
                60
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                4000
            </td>
            <td>
                5000
            </td>
            <td>
                6000
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                42
            </td>
            <td>
                52
            </td>
            <td>
                62
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Pls note I have taken two hidden var for current page and per page item count.Now the jquery I hvae so far written.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


                    debugger;
                    var show_per_page = 3;
                    var number_of_items = $('#paginate tr').size();
                    var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items / show_per_page);
                    $('#current_page').val(1);
                    $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);
                    var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:callPrev();">Prev</a>' + '&nbsp';
                    var current_link = 1;
                    while (number_of_pages > current_link) {
                        navigation_html += '<a class=page_link" href="javacsript:showPage(' + current_link + ')" longdesc="' + current_link + '">' + (current_link + 1) + '</a>' + '&nbsp';
                        current_link++;
                    }
                    navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';
                    $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);
                    $('#paginate tr').css('display', 'none');
                    for (var i = 0; i < show_per_page; i++) {
                        $('#paginate tr').eq(i).css('display', 'block');
                    }


    });
```

It is working and created the paging bar.But now I am somehow lost how I will handle next() and callPrev() these two functions as I have to write definition for it.

Please bear with me as I am learning jquery.
Thanks.

Comment: suggest  using `slice()` as well as some `data-` attributes on pageing links to help with filtering

Comment: Thanks for replying.My problem is to create next function and callPrev function.Would you pls mind to elaborate what you mean.

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8vwm2f4a/2

Comment: thanks charlietfl its working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
next = function () {
   new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
   showPage(new_page);
}

previous = function () {
   new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
   $('#current_page').val(new_page);
   showPage(new_page);
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3qu7u4ej/1/

Comment: what is "page" passed as a parameter to _makepager_ function. ?

Comment: @RahulChaudhari, Current page number will be passed to showPage() function as a parameter and inside showPage() function we will call makePager() function with current page number as a parameter.